# py2neo - Functions like COUNT(),MIN(),MAX() in py2neo Api.(without using cypher.execute)

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

HI,
         I am new to Py2neo API. I have good knowledge using cypher but my requirement is to run python API (instead of cypher.execute("****")), because of performing analytics operation on graph.

I want a way to find the no of nodes in the graph, which is equivalent to **MATCH n RETURN COUNT(n)**.

Comment: Why do you have to use py2neo?

Comment: I want to compare cypher.execute() vs API operations, in terms of time taken to return the result(for some analytics operation). Count is a basic analytical operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Graph` object has a `order` attribute (http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Path.order)

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph()

print(graph.order)
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want to compare cypher.execute() vs API operations"

To what end? Most of the API operations are backed by Cypher calls.

Comment: Basically, I work with streaming data. So, I want a way to complete the operations with low latency.

Comment: The higher-level API will not give you any lower latency than Cypher calls. The former simply wraps the latter.